# is n! in the order of Theta((n+1)!)? can you show me a proof?

Tags: math, big-o, factorial

I'm trying to figure how to prove or disprove this equation can somebody help me ?

My first thought will be:

`for f (n) = n! and g (n) = (n + 1)!  =>  f(n) = Theta(g(n))`

we must find a c1 and c2 R + and n1 E N such that

`c1g (n) <f (n) <c2g (n) for all n> n1`

C2 its simple because n < n+1 but c1 its another case, because if a put c1= 0.5 i think a will have something < n but when a put it on a graph simulator they say that c1g(n) its bigger at some point... i need help please

Comment: No they talk about n-1 and in my case is the not n+1 ! theta(n!) but the other way n! Theta((n+1)!)

Comment: @YanickMarion Define `m=n+1`. `(m-1)!` is in `Theta(m!)` if and only if `n!` is in `Theta((n+1)!)`. Does that answer your question why these are identical?